# Probability related, dice problem

Tags: probability, dice

A dice is turned randomly from one face to one of four adjoined faces. Suppose we start from the position with the number 6 on top. Find the probability $P_n$ that after $n$ such turns the dice will show the number $6$ again on top. Find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P_n$ .

Comment: there's 3 states the die can be in, 6 at the top, 6 at the side, 6 on the bottom - you could work on a recurrence relation based on the probability of the die going to those states - for n = 1 it p= zero, and for n=2 p= 1/4 - then on?

Comment: I think the key to it is getting the probability that it is on the middle band at n-1 turns, then from there it can go to 6 with probability 1/4 on the next turn, otherwise it can't

Answer (score 2):

After the first step the $6$ will be on the side of the dice (neither up or down). After that due to symmetry it will be as probable that it is up that it is  down.

We have that if the $6$ is on top or bottom the next step it will be on the side certainly. OTOH if it's on the side it will be $1/4$ chance that it will be on top next step and $1/4$ chance that it will be at the bottom at the next step. In total this means that when on side it will be $1/2$ chance that it will remain on the side and $1/2$ chance that it will be at top or bottom next step.

This means that the probability of the $6$ being on top or bottom is half the probability that it was at the side the previous step which is the complementary event that it's at top or bottom. Let $S_n$ be the event that the $6$ is on the side and $T_n$ is that it is not (ie top or bottom). We've see that $\Pr(T_{n+1}|T_n) = 0$ and $\Pr(T_{n+1}|S_n) = 1/2$. Let $Q_n$ be the probability that it's at top or bottom we have:

$$Q_{n+1} = \Pr(T_{n+1}) = \Pr(T_{n+1}\cap T_n) + \Pr(T{n+1}\cap S_n) 
= \Pr(T_{n+1}|T_n)\Pr(T_n) + \Pr(T_{n+1}|S_n)\Pr(S_n) \\= {1\over 2}\Pr({S_n}) = {1\over 2}(1-\Pr(T_n)) = (1-Q_n)/2$$

And $Q_n = 2P_n$ by symmetry and therefore we have:

$$P_{n+1} = (1-2P_n)/4$$

or

$$P_n = {1+2\cdot (-2)^{-n}\over 6}$$

which can be proven by induction (with the initial condition $P_1 = 0$. Therefore we have $\lim P_n = 1/6$ as expected.

Comment: Hello, @skyking can you kindly check of the answer is

$P_n=\frac{1}{6}[1+2*(-2)^{-n}]$

Comment: @lallu-bhoot Yes, that's correct - I was sloppy when I checked my first solution (and have updated the answer). The thing you need to do with the expression is to verify that $P_1 = 0$ and $1-2P_n = 4P_{n+1}$ which now passes.

Comment: Hi, @skyking can you please elaborate why we can write- $Q_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(1-Q_n)$

Comment: Yes, $1-Q_n$ is the probability that the six is on the side, from there it's $1/2$ chance that it will stay on the side and $1/2$ chance that it will be on top or bottom. $Q_n$ is the probability that the six is on top or bottom and from there it will certainly go to an edge so the chance it will end up on top or bottom then is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q_n$ denote the probability that the face opposite to face $6$ is on top after $n$ turns.

By symmetry we find that: $$P_n=Q_n\text{ for }n=1,2,\dots\tag1$$

Next to that we have: $$P_n=\frac14(1-P_{n-1}-Q_{n-1})\text{ for }n=1,2,\dots\tag2$$ and combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find: $$P_n=\frac14-\frac12P_{n-1}\text{ for }n=2,3,\dots$$

Of course we start with $P_0=1$ and $P_1=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is Markov chain with state set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and transition probability matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&0\\
\frac14&0&\frac14&\frac14&0&\frac14\\
\frac14&\frac14&0&0&\frac14&\frac14\\
\frac14&\frac14&0&0&\frac14&\frac14\\
\frac14&0&\frac14&\frac14&0&\frac14\\
0&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

(I don't know if my die is a standard one but I could get the neighboring faces by looking at my die.)

It is easy to check that the stationary probabilities are $\left[\frac16\ \frac16\ \frac16\ \frac16\ \frac16\ \frac16\right].$

So,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\begin{bmatrix}
0&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&0\\
\frac14&0&\frac14&\frac14&0&\frac14\\
\frac14&\frac14&0&0&\frac14&\frac14\\
\frac14&\frac14&0&0&\frac14&\frac14\\
\frac14&0&\frac14&\frac14&0&\frac14\\
0&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&\frac14&0.
\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\
\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16
\\\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16
\end{bmatrix}.$$

From the sixth power of the state transition matrix we can tell that the probability of getting $6$ after six steps starting with six is:

$$P(S_6=6\mid S_1=6)=\frac{11}{64}\approx \frac16.$$

Comment: Overly detailed, but one can move on by noting that if $O$ is all ones matrix and $X$ is the ones in "X" matrix we have that the above matrix is $(O-X)/4 = O/6 + (O-3X)/12$ and note that $O(O-3X)=(O-3X)O=0$ and $O^2 = 6O$ and $(O-3X)^2 = - 6(O-3X)$ one can see that $((O-X)/4)^n = O + (-2)^n(O-3X)/6$ or something like that. One sees then that $\lim ((O-X)/4)^n = O/6$ as you claim.

Comment: @skyking: To be honest I did not think at all about the stationary probabilities. I sort of knew that they had to be $1/6, 1/6,...$ because of vague symmetry reasons. Then I only checked if it worked. Then $O/6$ follows. Thank you for your remark.